# Converting this javascript regex validation function to php code

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I want to convert this javascript code to php code

```
function testPattern(iString) {

var iPattern = /[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}[1-9A-Za-z]{1}[Zz1-9A-Ja-j]{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]{1}/;

var patt = new RegExp(iPattern),
isPatternValid = patt.test(iString);
return isPatternValid;
}
```

i tried this php code but not working

```
function testPattern($iString) {

$iPattern ="/[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}[1-9A-Za-z]{1}[Zz1-9A-Ja-j]{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]{1}/";

$isPatternValid = preg_match($ipattern, $istring);

return $isPatternValid;

}
```

Comment: do you understand that `{1}` is a meaningless quantifier? Not that this is your issue, the regex you've got is very basic, so, I guess if you describe what you mean by "is not working" that would be a good start ... i.e., what is your input `$iString` and what is the output `$isPatternValid` ... and what do you expect it to be?

Comment: i am trying to return true or false but the result is always false;

Comment: Ex:   this  should return true 29AAGCR4375J1ZU  and changing any one character will return false. this code is working in javascript but not in php

Comment: well ... https://regex101.com/r/8ly98V/1 confirms you're correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In PHP, Variable names are case-sensitive**

- Second letter of your both variable(`$iString`,`$iPattern`) is capital and you are passing in
  lower case in preg_match(`$istring`,`$ipattern`)

[image]

check this :

```
function testPattern($iString) {


$iPattern ="/[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}[1-9A-Za-z]{1}[Zz1-9A-Ja-j]{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]{1}/";

$isPatternValid = preg_match($iPattern, $iString);

return $isPatternValid;

}

echo testPattern("29AAGCR4375J1ZU");
```

Comment: i tried changing case . yes you are correct but still the result is same

Comment: Its working now. i had few more variables with different case. my bad. thanks for pointing out.